# How can I solve "Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand"? Vue.js 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My Vue.js component is like this:

```html
    <template>
        <div>
            <div class="panel-group" v-for="item in list">
                ...
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#purchase-{{ item.id }}" class="pull-right" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        Show
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="purchase-{{ item.id }}" class="table-responsive panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">
                ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            ...
            computed: {
                list: function() {
                    return this.$store.state.transaction.list
                },
                ...
            }
        }
    </script>
```

When executed, there exists an error like this:

> Vue template syntax error:
>
> id="purchase-{{ item.id }}": Interpolation inside attributes has
> been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 250, accepted):

Use JavaScript code inside `v-bind` (or shortcut ":"):

```
:href="'#purchase-' + item.id"
```

and

```
:id="'purchase-' + item.id"
```

Or if using [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) or later:

```
:id="`purchase-${item.id}`"
```

Comment: Any idea how to make this work for an object, instead of a string?

Comment: @MikedeKlerk just remove the brackets: If you're binding to an object `foo`, v1 syntax would be `:my-object="{{ foo }}"` and v2 syntax would be `:my-object="foo"`.

Comment: with the `<div>` tag: `<div :id="'purchase-id-' + item._id">`. Example rendering: `<div id="purchase-id-5bb254557e1cef3b4cc40529">`

Comment: What if you want to add to existing attributes? E.g. append some classes without overwriting them?

Comment: @AdamReis you can have `class` and `:class` for the same element. Vue.js will merge the two attribute. See there : https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/466181/

Or if you want to use only `:class` : https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/466183/

Answer (score 7):

Use v-bind or shortcut syntax ':' to bind the attribute.
Example:

```
<input v-bind:placeholder="title">
<input :placeholder="title">
```

Comment: But Can someone please help me why we can't use placeholder="{{ title }}"

Comment: interpolation has been removed from attributes, it is only used inside html elements now

Answer (score 7):

Just use

```
:src="`img/profile/${item.photo}`"
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're pulling data from an array of objects, you need to include *require('assets/path/image.jpeg')* in your object like I did below.

**Working example:**

```
people: [
  {
    name: "Name",
    description: "Your Description.",
    closeup: require("../assets/something/absolute-black/image.jpeg"),
  },
```

Using *require(objectName.propName.urlPath)* in the v-img element did not work for me.

```
<v-img :src="require(people.closeup.urlPath)"></v-img>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is too require the **file address**:

```html
<img v-bind:src="require('../image-address/' + image_name)" />
```

The complete example below shows **../assets/logo.png:**

```html
<template>
    <img v-bind:src="require('../assets/' + img)" />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "component_name",
    data: function() {
      return {
        img: "logo.png"
      };
    }
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If none of the previous answers work, do this specially in Vue-3 and Composition API:

```
:src="require(`../image/animal_image/${image}`)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant solution is save images outside Webpack. By default, Webpack compress images in [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), so if you save images in your assets folder, that doesn't work because Webpack will compress images in base64, and that *isn’t* a reactive variable.

To solve your problem, you need to save your images in your *public path*. Usually the public path is in "public" folder or "statics".

Finally, you can do this:

```
data(){
  return {
    image: 1,
    publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL
  }
}
```

And your HTML you can do this:

```
<img :src="publicPath+'../statics/img/p'+image+'.png'" alt="HANGOUT PHOTO">
```

**When to use the public folder**

- You need a file with a specific name in the build output
- File depends on a reactive variable that can change in execution time
- You have images and need to dynamically reference their paths
- Some library may be incompatible with Webpack and you have no other option but to include it as a <script> tag.

More information: *["HTML and Static Assets" in Vue.js documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder)*