# how to output vue3 variable in HTML nested quotation?

Tags: vuejs3

I am trying to output value from vue variable within quotation.

```
<div v-for="product in inventory" class="col">
   <div class="card shadow-sm">
      <div style="background-image: url('images/{{ product.img }}')"
                class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: If you want to use a variable in your template, use `v-bind:style` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining string & variable in element attribute in Vue component template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45451858/combining-string-variable-in-element-attribute-in-vue-component-template)

Comment: Sorry.  No really.

Comment: There’s a guide in the official docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-inline-styles