# Vue setting colspan

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Following keeps throwing an error:

```
<th style="padding-right: 0px;" v-for="n in modelClustersList"  colspan="{{modelClustersList.length}}">
```

Its kind of wierd I can use the {{modelClustersList.length}} other places. Is colspan somehow special in Vue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand ? Vue.JS 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211760/how-to-solve-interpolation-inside-attributes-has-been-removed-use-v-bind-or-the)

Comment: Looks like it. Will test asap. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use `v-bind` directive to manuplate html attribute,

```
v-bind:colspan="modelClustersList.length"
```

**shorthand:**

```
:colspan="modelClustersList.length"
```

Refer Vue docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes