# Setting id tag dynamically using vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a vue.js template that has a todo prop. I want to dynamically set the id value of each element. This what I have tried so far, is something like this possible and if not what are some other options?

```
<canvas class="canvas" id="cv`${{todo.id}}`" width="500" height="700"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This should work.

```
:id="`cv${todo.id}`"
```

or

```
v-bind:id="`cv${todo.id}`"
```

Or do it the old-school way if the browser doesn't support string interpolation:

```
:id="'cv' + todo.id"
```

This is essentially [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211760/how-to-solve-interpolation-inside-attributes-has-been-removed-use-v-bind-or-the) but I couldn't determine how to escape the backticks in a comment!

Comment: I was facing problem with laravel project with "{{}}" not working. But you solution solve all of my problem.. thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

This helped me to solve my problem :

`<input v-bind:id="object.value1" v-model="object.value2"/>`