# Searching with input

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I cant understand why, but my search field doesn't work with Vue.js correctly.

- First of all, I need to hide search results if it's not available.
- And my second problem is that I can't use variables where I need to.

P.S. Oh, I forgot, I need to delete space between div and 'li':
[sorry, I haven't access to post images because my reputation is low](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2m5Jn.png).
I'll put my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/4r2oqz2x/

Comment: I am really sorry for this kind of mapping, StackOverflow giving attention to jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line

```
            <a href={{ searchResult.href }}><img src={{ searchResult.img }}>
```

should be

```
           <a :href="searchResult.href"><img :src="searchResult.img">
```

See [How to solve Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand ? Vue.JS 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211760/how-to-solve-interpolation-inside-attributes-has-been-removed-use-v-bind-or-the)