# VueJS interpolation in src attribute

Tags: typescript, vue.js, src, vuetify.js

In a VueJS with TypeScript and Vuetify app, I have ten pictures called picture1.png, picture2.png, picture3.png, etc. I'm trying to make `<div><img src="../assets/pictures/picture1.png"/></div>` for each of them. Here's my code:

```
<template>
    <div class="home">
        <div class="pictures">
            <div v-for="index in Array.from({length: 10}, (v, k) => k+1)" :key="index">
                <img src='../assets/pictures/picture{{index}}.png'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

This has the error that interpolation in attributes has been removed. As explained to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211760/how-to-solve-interpolation-inside-attributes-has-been-removed-use-v-bind-or-the), you're supposed to use v-bind instead:

```
<template>
<div class="home">
    <div class="picture">
        <div v-for="index in Array.from({length: 10}, (v, k) => k+1)" :key="index">
            {{index}}
            <img :src="'../assets/pictures/picture' + index + '.png'">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That outputs ten broken images, as an example, with src literally like this:
`src="../assets/pictures/picture1.png"`

And that file doesn't exist, so it shows the broken image icon.

If I just use `<img src='../assets/pictures/picture1.png'>`, it works, and the image url as shown in the dom inspector is `<img src="/img/picture1.ea361a2e.png">`.

Is there a way to properly handle building img `src`s in Vue dynamically but still allow it to handle it the way it handles normal `src`s without dynamic binding?

Comment: I don't understand why the working url that you see in the dom inspector is different in path and filename. Either way, you could try `:src=\`path/to/image${index}.png\``.

Comment: @johan would it make a difference that I'm using a project generated with vue-cli 3 and npm run serve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had luck doing the following.

```
:src="require(`images/image-${index}.png`)"
```