# VueJs - put string inside of a img src attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to take a piece of data (specifically, the name of a job department) for a vue component, convert it to lowercase and append it into an image src to render the correct image. Because the images are simply just the names of the department.

Currently it looks like this:

```
<ul class="jobs-container">
  <li
      v-for="job in filteredJobs"
      :key="job.absolute_url"
      class="u-margin-bottom-small">
    <a :href="job.absolute_url" target="_blank">
      <img src="/wp-content/themes/theme/dist/images/icons/careers/engineering.svg" alt="Engineering" />
      <div>
        <h3 v-html="job.departments[0].name" />
        <span class="position" v-html="job.title" />
      </div>
      <span class="location" v-html="job.offices[0].location" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I need to do something like this:

```
<ul class="jobs-container">
  <li
      v-for="job in filteredJobs"
      :key="job.absolute_url"
      class="u-margin-bottom-small">
    <a :href="job.absolute_url" target="_blank">

      // insert name of job department
      <img src="/wp-content/themes/theme/dist/images/icons/careers/{{ job.departments[0].name.toLowerCase() }}.svg" alt="Engineering" />

      <div>
        <h3 v-html="job.departments[0].name" />
        <span class="position" v-html="job.title" />
      </div>
      <span class="location" v-html="job.offices[0].location" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This doesn't work and throws:

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors      4:02:34 PM
>
> error  in ./wp-content/themes/theme/assets/js/Careers.
>   vue?vue&type=template&id=bf690b58&
>
> Module Error (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loader
>   s/templateLoader.js): (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)
>
> Errors compiling template:
>
> src="/wp-content/themes/theme/dist/images/icons/caree rs/{{
>   job.departments[0].name }}.svg": Interpolation in side attributes has
>    been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example,
>   instead of `<div id="{{ val }}">`, use `<div :id="val">`.
>
> 30 |            class="u-margin-bottom-small">   31 |               32 |              
>        |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   33 |                 34 |

So then I go:

```
<img :src="/wp-content/themes/theme/dist/images/icons/careers/{{ job.departments[0].name.toLowerCase() }}.svg" alt="Engineering" />
```

Error:

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors      4:06:01 PM
>
> error  in ./wp-content/themes/theme/assets/js/Careers.
>   vue?vue&type=template&id=16c0d4b0&
>
> Module Error (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loader
>   s/templateLoader.js): (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)
>
> Errors compiling template:
>
> invalid expression: Invalid regular expression flags  in
>
> ```
> /wp-content/themes/theme/dist/images/icons/careers/{{ job.departments[0].name }}.svg
> ```
>
> Raw expression:
>   :src="/wp-content/themes/theme/dist/images/icons/careers/{{
>   job.departments[0].name }}.svg"
>
> 30 |            class="u-margin-bottom-small">   31 |               32 |              
>        |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   33 |                 34 |
>
> @
>   ./wp-content/themes/theme/assets/js/Careers.vue?vue&type=template&id=16c0d4b0&
>   1:0-223 1:0-223  @ ./wp-content/themes/theme/assets/js/Careers.vue  @
>   ./wp-content/themes/theme/assets/js/careers.js  @
>   ./wp-content/themes/theme/assets/js/main.js  @ multi
>   ./wp-content/themes/theme/assets/js/main.js
>   ./wp-content/themes/theme/assets/sass/base.scss

In the context of Vue how can I take `job.departments[0].name.toLowerCase()` and inject into the last part of `<img src="/wp-content/themes/theme/dist/images/icons/careers/(INJECT IT HERE).svg" alt="Engineering" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close, when you use the `binding` syntax, you need to wrap your actual URL in single quotes so it interps it as a string:

```
<img :src="'/wp-content/themes/theme/dist/images/icons/careers/' + job.departments[0].name.toLowerCase() + '.svg" alt="Engineering'" />
```

Or just throw the entire URL into a variable:

```
let someScopedVariable = '/wp-content/themes/theme/dist/images/icons/careers/' + job.departments[0].name.toLowerCase() + '.svg';

<img :src="someScopedVariable" />
```

Comment: DUH jfc should've tried that, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use template literals:

```
  <img :src="`/url/${name}.svg`" alt="Engineering" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Any literal text must be escaped with `'` if you use the colon shorthand since Vue interprets it as JavaScript. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211760/how-to-solve-interpolation-inside-attributes-has-been-removed-use-v-bind-or-the) for more information. The reason you're seeing the "Invalid regular expression flags" is because JavaScript interprets any text inside `/`es as a regular expression. E.G.:

`:src="'/wp-content/themes/theme/dist/images/icons/careers/' + job.departments[0].name + '.svg'"`