# Making slideshow in JavaScript with Vue and HTML but error 404 "Not found" for images

Tags: javascript, html, image, vue.js, slideshow

[image: The folder everything is in]Not sure if my solution to the buttons works for the previous and next image yet because I am not able to test them because none of the pictures are found. I have them all in the same folder and they are not misspelled. I am not sure why they cannot be found. Thank you all for helping.

The error: "GET /images[currentImage]" Error (404): "Not found"

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Slideshow</title>
      </head>
    <body>
    <div id="app">
      <button @click="previousImage">Previous image</button>
      <button v-on:click="nextImage">Next image</button><br><br>
      <img :src="images[currentImage]" :width="imageWidth">
    </div>
    </body>
    <script src="vue.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    </html>
```

app.js:

```
const customButton = {
    template: "<button>Custom button</button>"
};
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      currentImage: 0,
      images: ["meme1.PNG", "meme2.PNG", "meme3.JPG", "meme4.PNG"],
      imageWidth: 640
  },
  components: {
    customButton
  },
  methods: {
    nextImage() {
      if (currentImage == 0) {
    currentImage++;
    this.currentImage = (this.currentImage + 1) % this.images.length;
  }
  if (currentImage == 1) {
    currentImage++;
    this.currentImage = (this.currentImage + 1) % this.images.length;
  }
  if (currentImage == 2) {
    currentImage++;
    this.currentImage = (this.currentImage + 1) % this.images.length;
  }
  if (currentImage == 3) {
    this.currentImage = (this.currentImage + 1) % this.images.length;
  }
    },
    previousImage() {
        if (currentImage == 0) {
    this.currentImage = (this.currentImage - 1) % this.images.length;
  }
  if (currentImage == 1) {
    currentImage--;
    this.currentImage = (this.currentImage - 1) % this.images.length;
  }
  if (currentImage == 2) {
    currentImage--;
   this.currentImage = (this.currentImage - 1) % this.images.length;
  }
  if (currentImage == 3) {
    currentImage--;
    this.currentImage = (this.currentImage - 1) % this.images.length;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: please paste the full url that's generating the error message

Comment: Sorry about that. Is that what you meant, what i put in the description?

Comment: yep, exactly.  See what's happening? 
 You didn't tell `vue` to do anything with `src` so as far as vue is concerned, it's not managing `src` at all.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211760/how-to-solve-interpolation-inside-attributes-has-been-removed-use-v-bind-or-the

Comment: There are several problems with this code  1) As others said, your image has no binding so it's looking for an image whose filename is literally "images[currentImage]".  Binding is what lets Vue know that the attribute refers to an instance property.  2) In your next/previous methods, you need to refer to `this.currentImage` instead of just `currentImage`.  In the template, you omit the `this`, but in the instance scripting, you do not.  3) Methods are returning values but nothing is being done with those values, there is no need for the return statements.  4) `img` `width` needs a binding too

Comment: Arent they being binded in app.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Change your index.html like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Slideshow</title>
      </head>
    <body>
    <div id="app">
      <button @click="previousImage">Previous image</button>
      <button v-on:click="nextImage">Next image</button><br><br>
      <img :src="images[currentImage]" :width="imageWidth">
    </div>
    </body>
    <script src="vue.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    </html>
```

and you made many mistakes in your code, just check all sort of code.
here is another modification of data block

```
data: {
      currentImage: 0,
      test: "meme1.PNG",
      images: ["meme1.PNG", "meme2.PNG", "meme3.JPG", "meme4.PNG"],
      imageWidth: 640
  },
```

Comment: Okay I made some edits in my code and now the first image appears, but whenever i click the buttons, the image does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Use: v-bind:src

Instead of: src

Or you can refer to this ->
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html

If you are still having error, kindly post the structure of the folder and it's content. Thanks

Comment: that v-bind didnt seem to fix it. I will post the structure of the folder